# 'expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token' for default_random_engine

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, clang

I try my local compiler and online http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php. Both generates the same errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   default_random_engine gen((random_device())());

   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

I have used g++ to compile the above code and the error is as follows:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

g++ $1.cpp -o $1 -g -Wall -std=c++0x // error

However, I don't have such an issue with clang.

clang++ -o $1 -Werror $1.cpp -std=c++11 -O3 // fine

Question> can someone help me figure it out why? and how to correct it under g++ since I have to run g++ to debug my code.

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
clang version 3.4 (trunk 185180)

// Updated //

```
//http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: should be `gen(random_device())`?

Comment: @billz Still doesn't explain why the compiler returned a syntax error.

Comment: look at this sample: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random  @0x499602D2, I just feel he calls operator() maybe not right.

Comment: FWIW, compiles with gcc 4.8 and above.

Comment: Regarding `std::default_random_engine`,  C++11§ 26.5.5/10 "The choice of engine type named by this typedef is implementation-defined. [Note: The implementation may select this type on the basis of performance, size, quality, or any combination of such factors, so as to provide at least acceptable engine behavior for relatively casual, inexpert, and/or lightweight use. Because dierent implementations may select dierent underlying engine types, code that uses this typedef need not generate identical sequences across implementations."

Comment: Your updated code should work on your platform by simply replacing `std::mt19937` with `std::default_random_engine`. If thats the one you want to use, that is.